# Avatar appears outside of targeted area when adding it to a PHP messaging script

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this micro message system script and I want to add an avatar to it, however, my lack of PHP knowledge is making this difficult.

The code I use to display an avatar is:

```
userphoto_thumbnail($user_info, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(width => '40', height => '40'), $default_src = '')
```

And I want to inject this avatar to this part of the message script (inside a loop):

```
$r = $r . '<tr id="wpam-reply-' . $post->post_ID . '-' . $count . '" ' . $style . '>';
$r = $r . '<td style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px; width:40px;"><span title="' . $user_info->display_name . ' (' . $user_info->user_login . ')">' . userphoto_thumbnail($user_info, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(width => '40', height => '40'), $default_src = '') . '</span></td>';
$r = $r . '<td>' . wpam_get_message($reply, $user_info, $options, 2) . '</td>';
$r = $r . '</tr>';
```

If you look at the second line, you will see how I added it there. However, this does not return the avatar where it should be. It appears outside everything else. Maybe because it returns a string rather than data? I am not sure as I am only just familiarising myself with PHP terminology.

I am certain that I have not added the avatar code to the script correctly, can you assist?

EDIT: Just to clarify, on the HTML output, the avatar images appear outside of the table, when they should be inside the `<td style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px; width:40px;">` tag.

Comment: Are you using the HTML img tag?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Executing **userphoto_thumbnail($user_info, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(width => '40', height => '40'), $default_src = '')** returns: <img width="40" height="40" class="photo" alt="admin" src="http://url">

Comment: Is the generated URL correct? If no you'll have to post your userphoto_thumbnail function otherwise we'll have get our magic watching ball.

Comment: Oh yes the URL is perfectly fine. As I noted in my question, the avatar images does display, only they appear outside of where I target them to. In other words, there is nothing wrong with the userphoto echo. The problem is how I insert it with the messaging script.

Comment: What's the resulting HTML output you're getting for each row?

Comment: Probably a CSS positioning issue then...

Comment: It results like this: All IMG tags listed first, and **then** the message entries. So although the userphoto is executed in the second line of the script, it displays above everything else.

Comment: @LouisH. Haha no I assure it, this is not the case. Let me explain this better. You see how in the script, the avatar should be placed within the **<td style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px; width:40px;">** area? Well in the HTML output, it is above the entire table.

Comment: @GaryWoods - `userphoto_thumbnail` does return the text for the image rather than echoing it, doesn't it?

Comment: @andrewsi How do you mean the text? No, the image is perfectly visible. The problem is that on the HTML output, it is not placed where it should be. I have updated my answer to detail this.

Comment: Then show use the generated HTML and not just excerpts from it.

Comment: @GaryWoods - in `userphoto_thumbnail`, do you use a `return` or an `echo`?

Comment: @andrewsi I am afraid I do not know as userphoto_thumbnail is from a plugin. What do you propose? How would I adjust the script to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-photo/), it looks like `userphoto_thumbnails` prints out the image. You're trying to concatenate it instead. When you call it, it's being printed out when you're creating the string, so it's appearing in the wrong place.

Try this:

```
echo '<tr id="wpam-reply-' . $post->post_ID . '-' . $count . '" ' . $style . '>';
echo '<td style="padding:10px 0 10px 10px; width:40px;"><span title="' . $user_info->display_name . ' (' . $user_info->user_login . ')">';
userphoto_thumbnail($user_info, $before = '', $after = '', $attributes = array(width => '40', height => '40'), $default_src = '');
echo . '</span></td>';
echo '<td>' . wpam_get_message($reply, $user_info, $options, 2) . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

That will print everything out in the right place, though you're no longer creating the `$r` variable.

Comment: I just tested this and it did not work as proposed. Although I am quite certain that you are on the right track, is there any way to still use the $r value in your code example?

Comment: This is because the $r value is being used elsewhere within the script.

Comment: There's not much you can do - that function includes `echo`, so it will print out the image when it's called. There might be another function that returns the value, or you can just move the call to `userphoto_thumbnail` to where you use `$r`.

Comment: Alright brother, thank you very much regardless for your effort.

Comment: @GaryWoods - if you look in the support page for the documentation, there are a few other people with a similar propblem, and a couple of suggested workarounds: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-user-photo-how-to-return-photo-instead-of-echo-photo

Comment: Well, what do you know. I tweaked one of those workarounds and made this return the URL of the avatar which I put in an IMG tag: **$r = $r . $photoUrl = get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-content/uploads/userphoto/' . get_user_meta($user_info->ID, 'userphoto_thumb_file', true);** There goes without saying that your support for me to solve this has been more than excellent. Thank you very much, although your answer did not provide the correct solution, the link did - thus I have accepted this as the correct answer.

Comment: @GaryWoods - you should post your working code as an answer, too! Glad to have helped.

Comment: That is fine, it is better that you receive the points for this one as  it did solve my issue. Feel free to update your answer if you wish with the line of code that I posted above. Best of luck with your coding andrew.